# Converting HTML template to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I have a HTML theme. How to convert our HTML templates to Drupal 7 theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started with the following video tutorials:

- [Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_Fk5d8ovYg)
- [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr15GTUo0IU)
- [Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siWbRB4iCVg)
- [Part 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLBXY2Ig4go)

Hope this can get you on the right track... Muhammad.

Comment: None of the links work