# Building a Drupal Theme

Tags: php, templates, drupal-7

I want to build a drupal theme for my own business, but can't find any good resources on how to do it. I understand all the warnings of the complexity of Drupal and am willing to weather them, but the two chief questions I have about how to even begin building the site is:

1: Does anyone know of some good sites to learn how to build the PHP programs and run a Drupal engine?

2: Is it possible for me to start building the front end right now, all the HTML, CSS, and Javascript work, filling in all the content with dummy text, and then later "connect" the templates to the Drupal backend and database at a later point?

The help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1.If you want to learn PHP programming there is a course on Udemy (I have not tested it, am not vouching for it, just pointing it out: https://www.udemy.com/learn-php-programming-from-scratch/
However for building a Drupal site you don't need to learn to code PHP. It is a content management system that you can build from menus etc. So I would recommend just finding tutorials on how to set up and manage content on Drupal. You can find and installing a drupal 'theme' which is a template that you like and then can adapt. There are probably lots of Drupal how-to tutorials on Youtube. There are several online tutorials you can subscribe to eg https://drupalize.me.

2. Yes you can use dummy content and then later import to the Drupal site from an upload file or database. So for example you can import blogs/ articles, lists of names for user profiles etc from a spreadsheet file. That' a good way to get started is just build the front end, you can then move around the features on your site and add real content later.

Best wishes!

Comment: I recommend drupalize.me - some great step-by-step how to guides

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the [Drupal.org Theming Guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme)
2. Yes, it is possible. You can later do the HTML to Drupal work. Check [Converting HTML template to Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987529/converting-html-template-to-drupal-7)

Comment: Did this answer help you with your problem? If so please select it as a correct one or upvote it.